# How to migrate AMI to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, copy, amazon-ami

I want to migrate my application from AWS to GCP. In order tp replicate the same working copy i want to copy the AMI from aws to GCP.

Is it possible to migrate AMI to GCP

Do I need to use any other tool

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can export an AMI from AWS is if you first imported it from your own system into AWS. If you created the EC2 instance from an AMI located in the cloud you cannot export the instance as AWS does not permit this.

[Exporting an Instance as a VM Using VM Import/Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html)

Google Cloud supports importing operating systems installed to virtual disks including VMDK, VHD, and RAW.

[Migrating VMs to Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-migration/)